# Box.com API Update Metadata for file with cURL and PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am having problem with posting new metadata fields in Box.com. Here is my PHP cURL code which works but.

```
<?php

// $json = '{"op":"add","path":"/Hi","value":"xxx"}';
$ch = curl_init();
// print_r($json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/207843785204/metadata/global/properties");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "[{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": 
\"/Field\", \"value\": \"yesasssssa\"}]");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

This works all fine, but I want to add CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS JSON string as json php variable. And for Box API it works only with these backslashes \"op\" like it is now. I have cURL code line which works perfect -

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/207843785204/metadata/global/properties -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d '[{"op": "add", "path": "/Hi", "value": "no"}]' -X PUT
```

And it is converted in this site - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

I would like to know how can I dynamically add array keys and values with those slashes because it works only like that. Sorry for my English. Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking but you shouldn't roll-your-own JSON like that. Use `json_encode` instead, eg `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([['op' => 'add', 'path' => '/Hi', 'value': 'no']]))`

Comment: When I use your method it gives me -  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']' in C:\wamp64\www\demosite\index.php on line 134
Which is that line what you gave. Thanks

Comment: There are no braces in the code I gave you